# Using Dictionaries with numba njit function

Tags: python, dictionary, numba

How to speed up a funtion with numba when input and return are dictionaries?

I'm familiar with using numba for functions that accept numbers and return arrays, like this:

```
@numba.jit('float64[:](int32,int32)',nopython=True)
def f(a, b):
    # returns array 1d array
```

Now I have a function that accepts and returns dictionaries. How can I apply numba here?

```
    def collocation(aeolus_data,val_data):

      ...

      return sample_aeolus, sample_valdata
```

Comment: Hi @Annerl, and welcome to SO. To help us answer your question, could you say a bit more about which of numba's optimizations and modes you're trying to access? Have you tried the trouble-shooting tips in the [faqs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile)? Are you able to break your function down into smaller parts and applying the `@numba` annotation to them individually?

Answer (score 35):

The support for Dictionary has now been added in Numba version `43.0`. Although it quite limited  (does not support list and set as key/values). You can however read the updated documentation [here for more info](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#dict).

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

# First create a dictionary using Dict.empty()
# Specify the data types for both key and value pairs

# Dict with key as strings and values of type float array
dict_param1 = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64[:],
)

# Dict with keys as string and values of type float
dict_param2 = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64,
)

# Type-expressions are currently not supported inside jit functions.
float_array = types.float64[:]

@njit
def add_values(d_param1, d_param2):
    # Make a result dictionary to store results
    # Dict with keys as string and values of type float array
    result_dict = Dict.empty(
        key_type=types.unicode_type,
        value_type=float_array,
    )

    for key in d_param1.keys():
      result_dict[key] = d_param1[key] + d_param2[key]

    return result_dict

dict_param1["hello"]  = np.asarray([1.5, 2.5, 3.5], dtype='f8')
dict_param1["world"]  = np.asarray([10.5, 20.5, 30.5], dtype='f8')

dict_param2["hello"]  = 1.5
dict_param2["world"]  = 10

final_dict = add_values(dict_param1, dict_param2)

print(final_dict)
# Output : {hello: [3. 4. 5.], world: [20.5 30.5 40.5]}
```

[Link to Google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cuVNQJn20uB9n-9TXPZ2EXYJbLHxMquQ).

**References:**
 - https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3644
 - https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#dict