# Is there a way to speed up odeint in python

Tags: python, simulation, modeling, ode, odeint

currently I am trying to think about how to speedup odeint for a simulation I am running. Actually its only a primitive second order ode with a friction term and a discontinuous force. The model I am using to describe the dynamics is defined in a seperate function. Trying to solve the ode results in an error or extremely high computation times (talking about days).

Here is my code mostly hardcoded:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_ref(tspan):
    if tspan>2 and tspan<8:
        output = np.sin(tspan)
    elif tspan>=20:
        output = np.sin(tspan*10)
    else:
        output = 0.5
    return output

def model(state,t):
    def Fs(x):
        pT = 0
        pB = 150
        p0 = 200
        pA = 50
        kein = 0.25
        kaus = 0.25
        if x<0:
            pA = pT
            Fsres = -kaus*x*pA-kein*x*(p0-pB)
        else:
            pB = pT
            Fsres = -kaus*x*pB-kein*x*(p0-pA)
        return Fsres

    x,dx = state
    refnow = np.interp(t,xref.index.values,xref.values.squeeze())
    refprev = np.interp(t-dt,xref.index.values,xref.values.squeeze())
    drefnow = (refnow-refprev)/dt
    x_meas = x
    dx_meas =  dx
    errnow = refnow-x_meas
    errprev = refprev-(x_meas-dx_meas*dt)
    intrefnow = dt*(errnow-errprev)
    kp = 10
    kd = 0.1
    ki = 100
    sigma = kp*(refnow-x_meas)+kd*(drefnow-dx_meas)+ki*intrefnow
    tr0 = 5
    FricRed = (1.5-0.5*np.tanh(0.1*(t-tr0)))
    kpu = 300
    fr = 0.1
    m = 0.01
    d = 0.01
    k = 10
    u = float(kpu*np.sqrt(np.abs(sigma))*np.sign(sigma))
    ddx = 1/m*(Fs(x)+FricRed*fr*np.sign(dx)-d*dx-k*x + u )
    return [dx,ddx]
    
dt = 1e-3
tspan = np.arange(start=0, stop=50, step=dt)
steplim = tspan[-1]*0.1

reffunc = np.vectorize(create_ref)
xrefvals = reffunc(tspan)
xref = pd.DataFrame(data=xrefvals,index=tspan,columns=['xref'])

x0 = [-0.5,0]
simresult = odeint(model, x0, tspan)

plt.figure(num=1)
plt.plot(tspan,simresult[:,0],label='ispos')
plt.plot(tspan,xref['xref'].values,label='despos')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I change the code according to Pranav Hosangadi s comments. Thanks for the hints. I didn't know that and learned something new and didn't expect dictionaries to have such a high impact on computation time. But now its much faster.

Comment: Your question seems to be "How do I speed up a bunch of list comprehensions", not "how to speed up odeint". Can you please update your question to reflect this, and provide a [mre] that includes _only_ code relevant to your question? Hardcode sample inputs if you need to, instead of including code to calculate them from scratch.  Try to express `xrefvals` as a vector function of `tspan` instead of calculating it in a loop / list-comprehension. Then use `numpy`'s vectorized functions to calculate it.

Comment: One problem is that the right-hand-side ODE function has discontinuities in it: `if x<0:`... This is probably what is breaking your integration. `odeint` can not deal with this. `Assimulo` can. Check out this example: https://jmodelica.org/assimulo/tutorial_disc.html . Additionally, for speed, I would get rid of the pandas dataframe stuff (replace it with a numpy array). Also I would change `modelparamset` to a numpy array. Once everything was in numpy arrays, you could use numba `njit` with the `model` function.

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi for the suggestions. They were indeed necessary and helpfull. I changed to code according to your suggestions. One question: the advantage of using dicts is that you ,can collect everything in a structur instead of a loose bunch of variables floating around in your code. Is there a good practice tip to keep code structured and computationally efficient?

Comment: @nicholaswogan Thanks, I will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: @valvian . Dictionaries are OK. But if you want to use numba, you will need to use their dictionary feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078628/using-dictionaries-with-numba-njit-function .