# numba njit with signature for optional dict

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I want to program efficient function evaluations which depend on optional parameters.
For creating the signature involving Python dict [I followed the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078628/using-dictionaries-with-numba-njit-function).

Working example:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional

from numba.core import types
from numba.typed import Dict

@numba.njit(
    [
        'float64[:](float64[:],DictType(unicode_type, float64))',
        'float64[:](float64[:],none)',
    ]
)
def f(x: np.ndarray, p: Optional[dict[str, float]] = None) -> np.ndarray:
    x_ = x.copy()
    if p is not None:
        for k, v in p.items():
            x_ = x_ + float(v)  # work-around for errors caused by x_ += v

    return x_

x = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
p = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64,
)
p['a'] = 4.
p['b'] = 5.

print(f(x, p))
>>> [10., 11., 12.]
print(f(x))
>>> Exception has occurred: TypeError X
No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64, 1d, C), omitted(default=None)
  File "/example.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(f(x))
          ^^^^
TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64, 1d, C), omitted(default=None)
```

Calling the function without the optional argument throws above error.

I tried alternative signatures such as

```py
@numba.njit('float64[:](float64[:],optional(DictType(unicode_type, float64)))'
)
def f(x: np.ndarray, p: Optional[dict[str, float]] = None) -> np.ndarray:
```

and

```py
@numba.njit('float64[:](float64[:],optional(DictType(unicode_type, float64)))'
)
def f(
    x: np.ndarray,
    p: dict[str, float] = Dict.empty(
        key_type=types.unicode_type,
        value_type=types.float64,
    )
) -> np.ndarray:
```

but without success.

Python version: 3.11.4
numba version: 0.57.11

**Edit 01/19/2024:**

I am looking for a solution using signatures (not bare `njit`) in order to have it compiled up front and certain data types ensured.

Answer (score 1):

You can just omit the signatures and the numba will compile and run the code correctly (it just won't compile the function up front):

```py
from typing import Optional

import numba
from numba.core import types
from numba.typed import Dict


@numba.njit
def f(x: np.ndarray, p: Optional[dict[str, float]] = None) -> np.ndarray:
    x_ = x.copy()
    if p is not None:
        for k, v in p.items():
            x_ = x_ + float(v)  # work-around for errors caused by x_ += v
    return x_


x = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
p = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64,
)
p["a"] = 4.0
p["b"] = 5.0

print(f(x, p))
print(f(x))
```

Prints:

```
[10. 11. 12.]
[1. 2. 3.]
```

Comment: The point is I want it compiled up front and enforce the accepted data types.